# Logic names - current controller's name

Tags: symfony

This is some part of my code:

```
class FooController extends Controller {
   public function defaultAction() {
      return $this->render('myBarBundle:Foo:someview.html.twig');
   }
}
```

So every time I use rendering function I need to use current bundle and controller's name. And I was just curious, is there something that could shorten up this syntax a bit and kind of load current bundle/controller? So that I need to type just a view file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is the [@Template](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html) annotation provided by [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html) which comes with symfony2 standard edition.

```
// YourBundle/Controller/YourController.php

/**
 * @Template
 */
public function defaultAction(Post $post)
{
}

// this will automatically render 'YourBundle:YourController:default.html.twig
```

In this case all method arguments are automatically passed to the template if the method returns null and no vars attribute is defined!

... Or if you want to specify a specific Template, use:

```
/**
 * @Template ("SensioBlogBundle:Post:show")
 */
```

... you might aswell have a look at the @ParamConverter annotation.

**Attention**

If you just want to serve a **static** template ( like in your example ) without having to write a controller/action you can use the provided FrameworkBundle:Template:template controller. Read more about it [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html).

```
acme_privacy:
    path: /privacy
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template: 'AcmeBundle:Static:privacy.html.twig'
```